# How can I fill the gaps and then continue this sequence?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sequence

The code I have looks at the last active device used in the sequence and then continues it. If there is a gap in the sequence that is not currently being used I would like to fill it. How can I build that into the code?

Script works as expected as written for next in sequence. I'm not sure where to begin with adding a feature to fill in the gaps.

Input:

```
bash script WABEL8499IPM 3
```

Script:

```
 SRCFILE="~/Desktop/deviceinfo.csv"  
 LOGDIR="~/Desktop/"  
 LOGFILE="$LOGDIR/DeviceNames.csv"  

 # base name, such as "WABEL8499IPM"
 device_name=$1
 # quantity, such as "2"
 quantityNum=$2

 # the largest in sequence, such as "WABEL8499IPM108"
 max_sequence_name=$(cat $SRCFILE | grep -o -e "$device_name[0-9]*" | sort --reverse | head -n 1)

 # extract the last 3digit number (such as "108") from max_sequence_name
  max_sequence_num=$(echo $max_sequence_name | rev | cut -c 1-3 | rev)

 # create a sequence of files starting from "WABEL8499IPM101"  if there is not any "WABEL8499IPM". 
 if [ -z "$max_sequence_name" ]; then    
    max_sequence_name=device_name
    max_sequence_num=100
 fi

 # Fill In Sequence If Any Spots are Available If 101, 102, 104, 
 # 105, 106, 107 and 108 are used I want to output 103 (to fill in), 
 # 109 and 110 (to continue sequence).
 # create new sequence_name
 # such as ["WABEL8499IPM109", "WABEL8499IPM110"]


 array_new_sequence_name=()
 for i in $(seq 1 $quantityNum); do
cnum=$((max_sequence_num + i))
array_new_sequence_name+=($(echo $device_name$cnum))
 done

 #CODE FOR CREATING OUTPUT FILE HERE
 #for fn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]}; do touch $fn; done;

 # write log
 for sqn in ${array_new_sequence_name[@]};
 do
     echo $sqn >> $LOGFILE
 done
```

Actual result as written:

```
  #OUTPUT FROM WABEL8499IPM, 3
  #IF WABEL8499IPM101,102,104,105 ARE USED THEN OUTPUT IS THIS: 
  WABEL8499IPM106
  WABEL8499IPM107
  WABEL8499IPM108
```

Desired/Expected Result:

```
  #OUTPUT FROM WABEL8499IPM, 3
  #IF WABEL8499IPM101,102,104,105 ARE USED THEN OUTPUT IS THIS: 
  WABEL8499IPM103
  WABEL8499IPM106
  WABEL8499IPM107
```

Basically in my current script I'm making an API call to see what is currently enrolled into an MDM and then looking at the highest number in the sequence and outputting the next number in the sequence. The goal is to fill in the sequence if there are any gaps where the sequence isn't completed.

Comment: Did you copy it correctly? `+=($(echo $device_name$cnum))` is not a valid statement, it's missing the variable at the beginning.

Comment: I didn't. Should be fixed now.

Comment: What if the sequence is `103,104`? Do you want to output `101,102,105...`?

Comment: You showed us actual output and expected output but you didn't show us the input - add that to your question so we can start trying to help you.

Comment: @mickp yes, exactly. In the example I give 101,102,104 and 105 are in use so I would want 103,106 and 107. If the opposite is true like you asked then I want the output just to fill in first and then continue the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# create a test source file

$ cat > src_file <<-EOF
foo WABEL8499IPM102 bar WABEL8499IPM108 foo bar
WABEL8499IPM106
foo WABEL8499IPM104
foo bar
WABEL8499IPM105 WAbel8499IPM110 bar
EOF
```

```
# the actual code

$ cat script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pre=$1
num=$2
f=src_file
s=101

((num==0)) && exit

grep -oP "$pre\K[0-9]+" "$f" | sort -n > tmp 

comm -13 tmp <(seq $s $((s+num+$(wc -l < tmp)))) | awk -v n=$num -v p="$pre" '{print p $0}NR>=n{exit}'
```

```
# execute the script

$ ./script WABEL8499IPM 5
WABEL8499IPM101
WABEL8499IPM103
WABEL8499IPM107
WABEL8499IPM109
WABEL8499IPM110
```

Comment: I haven't had much luck as I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: @joshuaspatrick I included a test run to demonstrate how to use the code.